# Gitlab CI : ./bin/phpunit: No such file or directory

Tags: symfony, phpunit, gitlab-ci

I try to understand how to use Gitlab CI in a laravel project with *PHPUnit*. As written in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html) of Laravel, I have added the *PHPUnit-bridge* with `composer require --dev symfony/phpunit-bridge`
.

**MY `gilab-ci.yml` file**

```
image: php:7.2-cli
services:
    - mysql:latest
cache:
    paths:
    - vendor/

stages:
    - connect
    - test
    - deploy

variables:
    # Configure mysql service (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
    MYSQL_DATABASE: deshautsdebats
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: root

before_script:
    - apt-get update -yqq
    - apt-get install git -yqq zlib1g-dev
    # Install mysql driver
    - docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip
    # Install composer
    - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
    # Install all project dependencies
    - php composer.phar install

test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - ls -lad bin/
        - ./bin/phpunit
```

When I enter `./bin/phpunit` in local it works but when it's made by the CI if says :

> /bin/bash: line 90: ./bin/phpunit: No such file or directory

I tried to replace `./bin/phpunit`by `./vendor/bin/phpunit` but it throws the same error... Do you have any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Okay, I solved this by following [those steps]( https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/php.html)

Comment: Symfony uses "symfony/phpunit-bridge" for Unit test. This package download and install phpunit. Commit your local bin/phpunit to repo and add to gitlab cache bin/.phpunit directory.

Comment: @AntoineD you could post your comment above as an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure this out by following [those steps](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/php.html)